# Optimization criteria for R's ets function

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

When using the `ets` function in R's `forecast` package, what objective function is being optimized when `opt.crit="amse"`? (I'm fitting a linear additive model.)

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/7.3/topics/ets) mentions "average MSE over first `nmse` forecast horizons", so would that be

```
(MSE_1 + MSE_2 + ... + MSE_nmse)/nmse
```

where `MSE_i` is the mean squared error associated with `i`-step forecasts? If so, is there a way to configure the `ets` function to just optimize with respect to `MSE_nmse`?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late answer but could be helpful for others. Your understanding of `"amse"` and `nmse` is correct. But `nmse` is only used if you use `opt.crit = "amse"`. So if you simply want to optimize with respect to `MSE_nmse` then you should not use `"amse"` but `opt.crit = "mse"`.

Hope it helps :)